# SAS sum by group and then create new variable for each group

Tags: sas

I want to do summation for each group and create a new variable for the sum for each group. I tried proc sql, but it only created a new variable.
My dataset looks like:

```
data have;
input firm year product$ value;
datalines;
1 2012 a 5
1 2012 a 6
1 2012 b 3
1 2013 a 4
1 2013 a 3
1 2013 b 4
1 2013 b 3
2 2012 a 5
2 2012 a 6
2 2012 b 3
2 2012 b 4
2 2012 b 2
2 2013 a 4
2 2013 a 5
2 2013 b 3
2 2013 b 3
;
run;
```

what I want is a table with four columns: firm year productA_sum productB_sum.

I tried this way:

```
proc sql;
create table h.want as
select a.*, sum(a.value) as sumvalue
from h.have as a
group by firm, year, product;
quit;
```

But it only create a new column.

Comment: If you don't want all of the original data then do not include variables that are neither grouping keys or aggregate functions.  When you do that SAS has to remerge the aggregate values onto all of the original observations to be able to return all of the values of those variables. Your query is including VALUE.in the output.

Answer (score 1):

because u group three variables, but in the select, you choose all variables. it will cause group by function useless.

```
/*Try this one*/     
proc sql;
    create table h.want as
    select a.firm, a.year, a.product, sum(a.value) as sumvalue
    from h.have as a
    group by firm, year, product;
    quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get separate SUM() results based on another variable's value you need to use a CASE statement, not include it in the grouping variables.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
  select firm, year
       , sum(case when (product='a') then value else . end) as sum_product_A
       , sum(case when (product='b') then value else . end) as sum_product_B
  from have
  group by firm,year
;
quit;
```

If you want the sum to be zero instead of missing if the product never appears then replace the missing values in the else clauses with 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are pivoting an aggregate sum. A two step approach could be more desirable if there are more than two product values to contend with.

```
proc summary data=have nway noprint;
  class firm year product;
  var value;
  output out=class_sums sum=sum;
run;

proc transpose data=sums suffix=_sum out=want(drop=_name_);
  by firm year;
  id product;
  var sum;
run;
```